# Not counting characters right in text file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, io, count

I am doing another program with text file I/O and i'm confused because my code seems perfectly reasonable but the result seems crazy. I want to count the number of words, characters, sentances, and unique words in a text file of political speeches. Here is my code so it might clear things up a bit.

```
#This program will serve to analyze text files for the number of words in
#the text file, number of characters, sentances, unique words, and the longest
#word in the text file. This program will also provide the frequency of unique
#words. In particular, the text will be three political speeches which we will
#analyze, building on searching techniques in Python.
#CISC 101, Queen's University
#By Damian Connors; 10138187

def main():
    harper = readFile("Harper's Speech.txt")
    print(numCharacters(harper), "Characters.")
    obama1 = readFile("Obama's 2009 Speech.txt")
    print(numCharacters(obama1), "Characters.")
    obama2 = readFile("Obama's 2008 Speech.txt")
    print(numCharacters(obama1), "Characters.")

def readFile(filename):
    '''Function that reads a text file, then prints the name of file without
'.txt'. The fuction returns the read file for main() to call, and print's
the file's name so the user knows which file is read'''
    inFile1 = open(filename, "r")
    fileContentsList = inFile1.readlines()
    inFile1.close()
    print(filename.replace(".txt", "") + ":")  #this prints filename
    return fileContentsList

def numCharacters(file):
    return len(file) - file.count(" ")
```

What i'm having trouble with at the moment is counting the characters. It keeps saying that the # is 85, but it's a pretty big file and i know it is supposed to be 7792 characters. Any idea what i'm doing wrong with this? Here is my shell output and i'm using python 3.3.3

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Harper's Speech:
85 Characters.
Obama's 2009 Speech:
67 Characters.
Obama's 2008 Speech:
67 Characters.
>>>
```

so as you can see i have 3 speech files, but there's no way they are that little amount of characters.

Comment: Small glitch is that you're using `obama1` even when you expect `obama2` results.

Comment: `fileContentsList` has lines in the file. Not characters. So `len(file)` returns number of lines in the file

Comment: The answers below should fix it. Try creating a small, simple file where you know what the output should be, and try printing the variables as you go to check it looks how you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readlines` function returns a list containing the *lines,* so the length of it will be the number of lines in the file, *not* the number of characters.

You either have to find a way to read in all the characters (so that the length is correct), like using `read()`.

Or go through each line tallying up the character in it, perhaps something like:

```
tot = 0
for line in file:
    tot = tot + len(line) - line.count(" ")
return tot
```

(assuming your actual method chosen for calculating characters is correct, of course).

---

As an aside, your third output statement is referencing `obama1` rather than `obama2`, you may want to fix that as well.

Comment: Thank you, awesome answer, i'm glad you explained it to me as well, now i know for future coding.

Comment: I'm also having trouble with the counting words. I need to know how to remove all numeric characters... I am looking for an easy way to do this, my file has 1361 words (harper) and that's switching all hyphens, double spaces, \n, all to just spaces, then using split to count the spaces...I have done this, but i need to remove all numbers as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should change this line `fileContentsList = inFile1.readlines()` 
Now you are counting how many lines obama has in his speech. 
change readLines to read() and it will work

Comment: And for your other comment, That's how you can remove all numbers from your string`result = ''.join([i for i in your_string if not i.isdigit()])`  @DamianConnors

Answer (score 0):

You are instead counting lines. In more detail, you are effectively reading the file into a list of lines and then counting them. A cleaned up version of your code follows.

```
def count_lines(filename):
    with open(filename) as stream:
        return len(stream.readlines())
```

The easiest change to such code to count words is to instead read out the whole file and split it into words and then count them, see the following code.

```
def count_words(filename):
    with open(filename) as stream:
        return len(stream.read().split())
```

Notes:

- The code may need to be updated to match your exact definition of words.
- This method is not suitable for very large files as it reads the whole file into memory and the list of words is also stored there.

Therefore the above code is more a conceptual model than the best final solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently seeing is the number of lines in your file. As the fileContentsList will return a list, numCharacters will return size of list.

If you want to continue to use 'readlines', you need to count number of characters in each line and add them to get total number of characters in file.

```
def main():
    print(readFile("Harper's Speech.txt"), "Characters.")
    print(readFile("Obama's 2009 Speech.txt"), "Characters.")
    print(readFile("Obama's 2008 Speech.txt"), "Characters.")

def readFile(filename):
    '''Function that reads a text file, then prints the name of file without
'.txt'. The fuction returns the read file for main() to call, and print's
the file's name so the user knows which file is read'''
    inFile1 = open(filename, "r")
    fileContentsList = inFile1.readlines()
    inFile1.close()
    totalChar =0    # Variable to store total number of characters
    for line in fileContentsList:    # reading all lines
        line = line.rstrip("\n")    # removing line end character '\n' from lines
        totalChar = totalChar + len(line) - line.count(" ")    # adding number of characters in line to total characters,
                                                               # also removing number of whitespaces in current line
    print(filename.replace(".txt", "") + ":")  #this prints filename
    return totalChar

main() # calling main function.
```